# Scraping all comments under an Instagram post

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram

my previous questions was closed, but the suggested answer doesn't help me. Instagram comments has a very specific behaviour! I know how to programatically scroll a website down, but with the comments on Instagram is a bit different! I would appreciate if my question was not closed immediately because it really doesn't help. Woule ba grateful for help and not shutting me down! Thank you.

Here it is again:
I am trying to build a scraper that is saving the comments under an Instagram post. I manage to log in to the instagram through my code so I can access all comments under a post, but I seem to cannot scroll down enough times to view all comments in order to scrape all of them. I only get around 20 comments everytime.

Can anyone please help me? I am using selenium webdriver.

Thank you for your help in advance! Will be greatfull.

This is my function for saving the comments:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class Instagram_comments():
    def __init__(self):
        self.firefox_options = Options()
        self.browser = Firefox(options=self.firefox_options)

    def get_comments(self, url):
        self.browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)


        while True:
        try:
            self.load_more_comments = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name(
                    'glyphsSpriteCircle_add__outline__24__grey_9')
            self.action = ActionChains(self.browser)
            self.action.move_to_element(self.load_more_comments)
            self.load_more_comments.click()
            time.sleep(4)
            self.body_elem = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('Mr508')
            for _ in range(100):
                self.body_elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
                time.sleep(3)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

        time.sleep(5)
        self.comment = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('gElp9 ')
        for c in self.comment:
            self.container = c.find_element_by_class_name('C4VMK')
            self.name = self.container.find_element_by_class_name('_6lAjh').text
            self.content = self.container.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
            self.content = self.content.replace('\n', ' ').strip().rstrip()
            self.time_of_post = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a/time').get_attribute("datetime")
            self.comment_details = {'profile name': self.name, 'comment': self.content, 'time': self.time_of_post}
            print(self.comment_details)
            time.sleep(5)

    return self.comment_details
```

Comment: Instagram is not the best site for bots to automate -- your previous question was likely closed because no one wants to write this code for you. This code sample is also long and difficult to debug -- posting a minimum reproducible example might get you some better feedback. Infinite scrolling is a tricky issue to solve because it is usually unique to each website. The best strategy I can offer you is to keep track of the 'last' comment in your comments list, scroll to the 'last' comment, and attempt to trigger a re-load of additional comments below it.

Answer (score 1):

This chunk worked multiple times for me:

```
def scroll():

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
        print('page height:', new_height)
    last_height = new_height
scroll()
```

and for some sites you will need to scrape as you scroll as not all elements will appear when you get to the bottom(such as twitter).

This is what my code looked like for twitter:

```
account_names = []
account_tags = []
account_link = []

def scroll():

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
global account_name

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page     
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)       
    account_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span')
    for act_name in account_name:
        global acctname
        acctname = act_name.text
        account_names.append(acctname)

    account_handle = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div/span')
    for act_handle in account_handle:
        global account_tags
        acct_handles = act_handle.text
        account_tags.append(acct_handles)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    account_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True, class_='css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1loqt21 r-1wbh5a2 r-dnmrzs r-1ny4l3l')
    for acct_links in account_links:
        global act_link
        act_link = acct_links['href']
        account_link.append(act_link)


    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

scroll()
```

Just a note: as another user commented, Instagram is very difficult to scrape because of the dynamic html variables, so they would be correct to say no one, myself included is too interested in writing that for instagram.

Answer (score 0):

The first function returns True if an element is found

The second function is used to scroll to the bottom till the last comment and then BeautifulSoup is used to scrape all comments

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(self,xpath):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

def get_comments():
        while self.check_exists_by_xpath("//div/ul/li/div/button"):
            load_more_comments_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/ul/li/div/button")
            load_more_comments_element.click()
            sleep(1)

        sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,'lxml')
        comms = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'C4VMK'})
        print(len(comms))
        soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(str(comms),'lxml')                            
        spans = soup_2.find_all('span')
        comments = [i.text.strip() for i in spans if i != '']
        print(comments)
```

I hope this helps - be aware I'm also still learning.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, this programmatically clicks the "load more" button, as many times it is displayed.

```
try:
    load_more_comment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.MGdpg > button:nth-child(1)')
    print("Found {}".format(str(load_more_comment)))
    
    while load_more_comment.is_displayed():
        load_more_comment.click()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        load_more_comment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.MGdpg > button:nth-child(1)')
        print("Found {}".format(str(load_more_comment)))
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).